# vba to open find and replace dialogue box

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

What can I add to the bottom of this Sub that will simply open the Find/Replace dialogue box so I can use the "Find Next" button.

```
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Section 01 40 00 - Quality Requirements"
        .Replacement.Text = "Section 01 73 00 - Execution"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show one of Word's built-in dialog boxes, query the `Application.Dialogs` collection. When you type the opening parenthesis `(` a list of the `WdWordDialog` members should show up. Locate the one you need. (Note: they're ordered by the menu name where they *used to be located*, back in the pre-Ribbon days, sometimes back to the Word 2.0 days - depending on the age of the dialog box. That's why Find is `EditFind`.)

```
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind).Show
```

or

```
Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show
```

There are three basic commands for "running" the dialog boxes: `Display`, `Execute` and `Show`. The last is the one that runs it the way you would as a user in Word. The first puts it on screen but doesn't do anything (you can use that to get information from the dialog box), and `Execute` runs the dialog box with settings you pass to it without displaying it.

Another way to show the dialog box:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("ReplaceDialog")
```

Note that the command name is *case-sensitive*!

Comment: I added line at end but the Replace tab doen't function.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Section 01 40 00 - Quality Requirements"
        .Replacement.Text = "Section 01 73 00 - Execution"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
     Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind).Show
   End With
End Sub

Comment: Thanks but I'm not able to scroll the doc with the resulting Replace window open.   .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
   
        Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Display

End Sub

Comment: Oh my Gosh. Yay. You code writers are brilliant. Many thanks.